# CLASS_NAME not declared - cannot dynamic_cast (target is not pointer or reference to complete type)

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{

};

class B: public A{
   public:
          void f(A *ptr){
               if(dynamic_cast<C *>(ptr)!=0){            // errors in this line
                   cout<<"ptr is pointing to C object\n";
               } 
          }                 
};

class C: public B{

};

int main(){

  A *aptr = new C();
  B *bptr = new B();
  bptr->f(aptr);

  return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this I get the error:

`'C' has not been declared.`

So I add a forward declaration `class C;` just above the code of `class B` and then try to compile it again but then it gives the error:

`cannot dynamic_cast 'ptr' (of type 'class A*') to type 'struct C*' (target is not pointer or reference to complete type)`

1) Why in the first error, `class B` cannot see its derived `class C` while they 're in the same .cpp file?

2) And why in the second error compiler says that `class C` is not a pointer to complete type?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `B::f()` later.

```
class B: public A{
public:
      void f(A *ptr);    
};
class C : public B { /* ... */ };

void B::f(A *ptr) {
           if(dynamic_cast<C *>(ptr)!=0){
               cout<<"ptr is pointing to C object\n";
           } 
}
```

As stated in C++ standard [expr.dynamic.cast],

> The result of the expression `dynamic_cast<T>(v)` is the result of
>   converting the expression `v` to type `T`. `T` shall be a pointer or
>   reference to a complete class type, or “pointer to *cv* void.”

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion worked! The only addition I had to make is to make `class A` polymporhpic by creating a virtual deconstructor in order to compile the code after your suggestion.